# Как убрать виджеты из QLayout визуально

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу после выбора из выпадающего меню `QComboBox` параметра - отображать `QLabel`, и при смене параметра в выпадающем меню `QComboBox`, хочу прошлый `QLabel`, очистить с `QHBoxLayout` и на его месте отобразить новый `QLabel`, просто заменять в `QLabel` содержимое мне не подходит.

```
QLabel* lb1 = new QLabel("Label1");
QLabel* lb2 = new QLabel("Label2");
QComboBox* cBox = new QComboBox();
QHBoxLayout* hBox = new QHBoxLayout();

cBox->addItem("First");
cBox->addItem("Second");

connect(cBox, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, [](){
   // Перед добавлением нужно удалить текущее содержимое layout, чтобы добавить новый 
   // QLabel
   if (cBox.currentIndex() == 0)
      hBox->addWidget(lb1);
   else 
      hBox->addWidget(lb2);

});
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#show и https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#hide

Comment: я бы еще вот на эту фигню порекомендовал обратить внимание, может предотвратить некоторые велосипеды https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html

Comment: @S.Nick Я так пробовал, я скрывал один элемент, а второй показывал, но получалось так, что первый элемент скрыт, но отображается то есть от него идет отступ и потом рисуется второй элемент

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Обязательно посмотрю

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Да, всё получилось, спасибо